# Issue proving a Formula to be Valid using Semantic Tableau

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, beth-tableau

I'm having issues proving that `((p ∨ q) → r) → (p → (q ∨ r))` is valid by means of a semantic tableau.

I know it is valid because I was able to prove it using the following Truth Table:

[image: Truth Table]

As far as I know, a semantic tableau is a test for satisfiability. And a formula is valid iff its negation unsatisfiable. Therefore I will need build a semantic tableau using the negation of the formula and prove that negation of the formula to be unsatisfiable, thus making the formula valid.

So this was my attempt to construct a semantic tableau for the formula:

[image: Semantic Tableau]

My problem is, there is only one closed branch for this semantic tableau that I've constructed. And as far as I know, all branches need to be closed in order for that negation formula to be invalid.

Any idea where I've gone astray?

Comment: The second step is wrong; the negation of $p \to (q \lor r)$ is a new node with $p$ **and** $\lnot (q \lor r)$. See your 1st (correct) step.

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is when you pass from the second to the third line: from 
\begin{align}
(p \lor q) \to r, \ \lnot (p \to (q \lor r))
\end{align}
you can't derive (as you wrote)
\begin{align}
(p \lor q) \to r, \ p \to \lnot(q\lor r)
\end{align}
but you can derive 
\begin{align}\tag{1}
(p \lor q) \to r, \ p, \ \lnot(q\lor r)
\end{align}

Developing the tableau from $(1)$ leads to close all branches, as expected.

Remember that, as a general rule in a tableau, a formula of the form $\lnot (A \to B)$ decomposes into $A, \ \lnot B$.

Comment: Thanks man! Totally dumb mistake on my end.